# Login to ASP website and then use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to grab data

Tags: php, html, asp-classic, authentication

I am using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" to parse data from a gaming ASP website. The data that i need to grab are only visible to registered users so i need something to log me in to site before start using it. Can someone suggest me a script or something which it can do this ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

don't know about Simple HTML DOM Parser login/cookie system. So you could use php's curl library to get in members area. Then use simple html dom parser..

Comment: yes i did the parse part! i just need help with the login system